# freetds with AWS RDS SQL Server - will it work

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, freetds

I have an existing setup in which an ec2 ubuntu machine with a PHP application is accessing a windows ec2 machine based sql server 2008 using freetds at ubuntu machine.

Now i am moving the sql server to a RDS database, will freetds still work with the RDS SQL server